# How to Add Nodejs Packages to Yocto?

Tags: node.js, npm, yocto, yocto-recipe

I would like to have an OS which support nodejs. In my yocto project at layer.conf file I add
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nodejs"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nodejs-npm"
which result in to have an OS with nodejs support afer bake. Now I want to add some NPM packages also like basic-auth etc.
would you please help me.
kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to add an `npm` package into your image, you need to create a recipe for it.

Yocto has an `npm` source scheme handler, and you can use `registry.npmjs.org` to create a recipe fetching your wanted package.

Create a recipe with devtool:

```
devtool add "npm://registry.npmjs.org;name=basic-auth;version=latest"
```

You can set a specific version as well.

The recipe would be the following:

- **basic-auth_2.0.1.bb** :

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)

SUMMARY = "node.js basic auth parser"
# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=42fffe6fe0b70501d52150ebb52113df \
                    file://node_modules/safe-buffer/LICENSE;md5=badd5e91c737e7ffdf10b40c1f907761"

SRC_URI = "npm://registry.npmjs.org/;name=basic-auth;version=latest"

NPM_SHRINKWRAP := "${THISDIR}/${PN}/npm-shrinkwrap.json"

inherit npm

# Must be set after inherit npm since that itself sets S
S = "${WORKDIR}/npmpkg"
LICENSE_${PN}-safe-buffer = "MIT"
LICENSE_${PN} = "MIT"
```

It compiles correctly.

You can move it to your custom layer after testing it with `devtool`:

```
devtool finish basic-auth <path/to/meta-custom> or
devtool finish basic-auth <layer/in/bblayers.conf>
```

For more information about `npm` handling check this [link](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/NPM)

I encourage you to read more about Yocto `NPM` handling in their official documentation in this [link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-node-package-manager-npm-packages)

**EDIT**:

If you encounter the error:

```
is missing the required parameter 'Parameter 'package' required'
```

just change `name` to `package` :

```
devtool add "npm://registry.npmjs.org;package=basic-auth;version=latest"
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks. With devtool I get this error "ERROR: URL: 'npm://registry.npmjs.org/;name=basic-auth;version=latest' is missing the required parameter 'Parameter 'package' required'". Any Idea about this error?

Comment: Check my EDIT. Just replace `name` to `package`

Comment: You are right. I managed it like : devtool add  "npm://registry.npmjs.org;name=basic-auth;version=2.0.1;package=basic-auth"

Comment: If my answer fixed your issue, it would be so helpful if you accept it as "Correct Answer"

Comment: still working on it, when I finished, sure. Many thanks up to now.

Comment: When I try to bake I face with this error : "ERROR: Failure expanding variable TUNE_FEATURES_tune-armv7at-neon, expression was ${TUNE_FEATURES_tune-armv7at} neon which triggered exception RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object "    any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any package which is available by Openembedded Layer in your Yocto release. Please look to [Openembedded Layer](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layers/) to find the package you want. After that, you can add any package via your **local.conf** file.

[Here is a third party library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062599/6394233)

If you don't find the package on the page, you need to compile it on your own using a compiler for your platform and add it manually by recipe.